# Тестирование Rest контролера Spring

Tags: spring, юнит-тесты, rest, mockito

Как тестировать Spring Rest controller, запросы к которому посылаются по https, с помощью mockito?

Comment: Привет, а что именно ты хочешь тестировать? Что уже получилось и какие конкретно трудности возникли?

Comment: Если вы хотите тестировать работу всего приложения в целом, то используейте `resassured` и в качестве субд `h2`

Comment: void helloWorld() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/helloworld"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().string("hello world"));
    }     ---- как мне написать подобный тест но только для  https протокола

Comment: трудности возникают с ssl сертификатом (я так думаю) , мне возвращается 401 код

Comment: Тестируя через MockMvc невозможно получить проблемы с сертификатом, потому что MockMvc не запускает реальный сервер, а эмулирует его, напрямую вызывая методы DispatcherServlet. Возможно, вы настроили Spring Security, а в тестах не авторизируетесь. Приведите ваш код, постарайтесь создать [минимальный самодостаточный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и добавить его в вопрос.